# Singularities of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the type of singularities of
$f(z)=e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}$ at $0,\infty$.
At $z=0$, if we consider the expansion of $f$ around 0, we see
$e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}=1+(z+\frac{1}{z})+ \cdots + \frac{1}{n!}(z+\frac{1}{z})^n+\cdots$
we see that the principal part has infinitely many terms. Hence, I can conclude that $z=0$ is an isolated essential singularity of $f$.
Again, to find the singularity at $\infty$, we have to consider the singularity of $f(\frac{1}{z})$ at 0. But we notice that $f(\frac{1}{z})=f(z)$. Thus,  we conclude that $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$ also. Am I doing it right?
Further, they have even asked to calculate the integral of $f$ around the circle $|z|=1$ taken in the anticlockwise sense. Well, if there is essential singularity at 0, then we can't apply the residue theorem. Then,  how can I calculate this integral?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Both $0$ and $\infty$ are essential singularities. Just to have a glimpse of that, try to restricts the limit to the real axis, and compute the limits for $x\to\pm\infty$ and $x\to 0^{\pm}$.

Comment: The residue theorem doesn't care about the type of singularity, as long as it is isolated. It is valid for removable singularities, poles, and essential singularities alike.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Yeah... I have got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about the type of singularity.

On the other hand,\begin{align}e^{z+1/z}&=e^ze^{1/z}\\&=\left(1+z+\frac12z^2+\frac1{3!}z^3+\cdots\right)\left(1+\frac1z+\frac12\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{3!}\frac1{z^3}+\cdots\right)\end{align}and therefore the coefficient of $\frac1z$ in the Laurent series of $f$ centered at $0$ is$$1+\frac12+\frac1{2\times3!}+\frac1{3\times4!}+\cdots\tag1$$So, the value of the integral that you're after is $2\pi i$ times $(1)$.

Comment: Yes Sir. But don't we find the coefficient of 1/z in the Laurent series around 0 when 0 is a pole?

Comment: What has that to do with this question? There is no pole here. As you wrote, what we have here is an essential singularity.

Comment: OK thank you so much sir.

Comment: @AdritaChoudhury $\int_{|z|=1}z^ndz=0$ for $n\ne -1$, then you need the Laurent expansion $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^n$ valid for $|z|\in (1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$, it converges absolutely/uniformly on $|z|=1$ thus $\int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n \int_{|z|=1} z^n dz= c_{-1} 2i\pi$. As you see no need that $z=0$ is a pole.